# script to process a list of ip addresses from a txt file and then confirm whether they are accessible or responding IPs within a xlsx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv, python-re, txt

I would like to be able to python script to process a list of IP addresses from a `txt` file and then confirm whether they are accessible or responding IP Addresses within a excel file.

I have seen the following, which I have used as a base but it doesn't seem to work or work as I would expect;

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extract-ip-address-from-file-using-python/

I was going somewhere along the lines of;

```
import re 
import csv 
f = open('C:/Users/dir/dir/iplogs.txt', 'r') #Text file with many ip address 
o = f.read() 
ip1 = re.findall( r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", o ) 
hosts = ip1 
for host in hosts:
```

However then I couldn't quite figure out how to manage this from here.

Comment: Do you have to do this in Python? This is exactly what the `nmap` tool is for.

Comment: So you're asking how to test whether an IP responds? That has nothing to do with regular expressions or exporting to CSV.

Comment: how might you suggest i do this? well i would like the end out put exporting to either csv or xlsx?

Comment: You could use the [`python-nmap`](https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/) library.

Comment: Exporting to CSV is simple, use the built-in `csv` module. There are dozens of tutorials on this.